# How to put active class to specific id/footer of a html page using angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I am using following directive for active class,but this doesn't get appplied to specific id on page

```
.directive('activeLink', ['$location', function (location) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
        var active = attrs.activeLink;
        var path = attrs.href;
        path = path.substring(1); //hack because path does not return including hashbang
        scope.location = location;
        scope.$watch('location.path()', function (newPath) {
          if (path === newPath) {
            element.addClass(active);
          } else {
            element.removeClass(active);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }])
```

Following is my navigation bar Home,About and products are different pages where the active class is getting applied. But "Contact" is a footer on home page where active class is not getting applied.How can I achieve it?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a active-link="active" href="#/" target="_self">Home</a></li>
    <li><a active-link="active" href="#/about" target="_self">About</a></li>
    <li><a active-link="active" href="#/products"  target="_self">Products</a></li>
    **<li><a active-link="active" ng-click="scrollTo('contact')" href="#/#contact" target="_self">Contact Us</a></li>**


</ul>
```

Comment: Any chance that you need to define `active` classat your home page as well? (inside the homepage css file)

Comment: Your talking about this??    --->  .active{color:blue;}

Comment: Yep. Are you sure it present in your homepage?

Comment: Yes its present..

Comment: Please inspect the `newPath` value (use console.log ,debugger, etc.). I suspect that when dealing with anchoring, your trick of `path.substring(1)` is just not working (path should be `/#contact` when clicking contact)

Comment: I tried inspecting  ,it shows-->  newPath="/"

Comment: `if (path === newPath || newPath == '/')` it's a workaround but it should work (note that if you have a multiple items leading to the same page you will have to modify this code)

Comment: not working bro

Answer (score 0):

Change `restrict: 'A'` to `restrict: 'E'`

Check once where you wrote ng-app , does footer included in ng-app?

Comment: Please edit your question to include some explanation for your answer. This will make it more valuable to the person asking the question, and to future visitors.

Comment: Change ng-click and Contact is not a page why you giving it as anchor tag.some examples for scroll down https://embed.plnkr.co/G5pMjsM6tswDUFxE3xer/      
       and        https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/y65G5/